# Removing 0 (NODATA) from Combochart in FeatureCollection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, null, feature-collection

I'm trying to make a combo chart based on two properties of a FeatureCollection.

However, one of the properties is full of 0 which I don't want to show them on the chart.

How can I not showing those with 0 value on the chart?

Here is  the code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/3946003969b252d0dec10f2e455309f4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the `features` with property value 0 using

`var test = test.filterMetadata("UKCount","not_equals",0)`

[Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/b57d2ad1f9bb8c67e4ca059e927b295f) to corrected code.